# AEM 6: sling:osgiconfig based on different environments

Tags: aem

I want to create sling:osgiconfig for different environment. I am aware that the folders will have to go by the naming convention `config.<runmode/environment>.<author/publish>`. We have different environments like https://test1-myapp.app.com or https://dev-myapp.app.com and so on. I logged into one of the environments in the publish mode to find out the runmode and all I could see was [crx3, nosamplecontent, publish, crx3tar]. This was the https://test1-myapp.app.com publish environment. I am not sure what name should I give to my config folder now.

Also, once I have it in place I am planning to fetch the properties as shown below:

```
SlingBindings bindings = (SlingBindings) slingRequest.getAttribute(SlingBindings.class.getName());
        SlingScriptHelper sling = bindings.getSling();
        Configuration conf = sling.getService(org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin.class).getConfiguration(pid);
        String[] myProp = (String[]) conf.getProperties().get("paths");
```

Will this work on different environments or it will keep fetching the same sling:osgiconfig node irrespective of the environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your server is running on the default runmodes / installation runmodes as they call it.

The **publish** is because it is a publish instance and **nosamplecontent** is generally used for Production installations where you would not like to have the sample content installed.

These are fixed runmodes and once installed with them, they cannot be changed thereafter.

However you can define your own runmodes such as dev or stage either through Sling Properties file `sling.run.modes=dev,author` or by adding system property in the start script like `-Dsling.run.modes=stage,publish`. More on this can be [found here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configure_runmodes.html#Using%20the%20sling.properties%20file).

With the default runmodes in place, it is difficult to have different configs for different instances. You can only have 2 configs one for author and the other for publish.

The configurations are picked up based on the run modes defined and hence your code would fetch the appropriate configurations wherever applicable in different environments.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is this something I can do using felix console ?

Comment: I dont think you can change it via felix. You might need to set it before starting your server. The link mentioned in the question would tell you how.